# Redirigir una URL desde una vista basada en clases a otra

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Al mover mi blog de WordPress a Django cambié la estructura de los enlaces permanentes, antes no usaba `category` en la estructura y ahora si. Mas o menos así:

```
/slug/ ⟼ /cat/slug/
```

Y entonces estoy recibiendo muchos errores 404, porque Django solo busca en categoría. Así que decidí agregar un buscador en la vista basada en clases de las categorías:

```
class CategoryDetail(ListView, CacheMixin):
    model = Entry
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.cat = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return Entry.objects.filter(
            category=self.cat, status=Entry.LIVE_STATUS).select_related() \
            .order_by('-pub_date', 'id')
```

En la función `get_queryset` quiero agregar un **redirect** que llame a la clase `EntryDetail` si el `slug` corresponde a una entrada y no a una categoría.

Lo hago así:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    try:
        entry = Entry.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return redirect(entry)
    except Entry.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    self.cat = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
    return Entry.objects.filter(
        category=self.cat, status=Entry.LIVE_STATUS).select_related() \
        .order_by('-pub_date', 'id')
```

Uso el `slug` para buscar la entrada (si **no la encuentra**, atrapo la excepción `DoesNotExist` y paso buscar la categoría) y si existe dicha entrada, redirecciono la petición a la entrada indicada, que contiene la propiedad `get_absolute_url()` tal como lo indica [la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) con `return redirect(entry)`. Pero no funciona.

Tampoco funciona si uso esta forma de `redirect`, que empata con el patrón de URL:

```
# En urls.py: 
# url(r'^(?P<cat>[-\w]+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', EntryDetail.as_view(), name="entry_detail")    
return redirect('entry_detail', cat=entry.category, slug=entry.slug)
```

El problema, en ambos casos, es que obtengo el error siguiente:

```
TypeError at /el-circulo/
object of type 'HttpResponseRedirect' has no len()
```

La función `len()` se usa para la paginación, porque la respuesta la sigo mandando a la CBV `CategoryDetail`.

#### ¿Cómo puedo hacer que funcione la redacción que necesito?

Es decir, como puedo salir de la clase que fue llamada por la petición y regresar la respuesta con otra clase distinta, en este caso con `EntryDetail`.

Comment: Hola, ¿los redirects los estás haciendo desde `get_queryset`? No estoy seguro de que sea el lugar correcto para hacer un HttpResponseRedirect, tal vez dentro del `get()`.

Comment: Si, desde get_queryset... en el segundo fragmento puse los intentos que he hecho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo imagino que el error:

```
TypeError at /el-circulo/
object of type 'HttpResponseRedirect' has no len()
```

Ocurre ya que estás retornando un `HttpResponseRedirect` en vez de un queryset que es lo que tendría que devolver el método `get_queryset`. Como mencionaba en mi comentario, no creo que este método se el lugar adecuado para una redirección.

Lo que yo haría sería pasar la redirección al método `get` y dejar la parte del queryset como la tenías inicialmente:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class CategoryDetail(ListView, CacheMixin):
    # ...

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'slug' in self.kwargs:
            try:
                entry = Entry.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
                return redirect(entry)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
        return super(CategoryDetail, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.cat = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return Entry.objects.filter(
            category=self.cat, status=Entry.LIVE_STATUS).select_related() \
            .order_by('-pub_date', 'id')
```

Comment: Exacto! Solo que no existe `Entry.DoesNotExist`, pero `django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist` funciona correctamente.

Comment: Quiero decir, que me equivoqué también en la excepción que buscaba atrapar.